# I can't get youtube video from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I use axios to get youtube data from
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY&part=snippet and then error show

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: `401` unauthorized, are you passing the correct credentials?

Comment: did you change `API_KEY` to be the actual api key?

Comment: I changed to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=z1k2R1-YPO4&key=AIzaSyAnAQwjKboJq51uY9QxIBgGd7GaY8AgNMM&part=snippet then error again and i try to put these link to website, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error means that you are unauthorised to access that resource. I assume that you are not inserting `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY&part=snippet` but are including the api key that you had been given?